# Fresh install of 18.04.2 Server kernelspace takes > 1 hour to boot

Tags: boot, 18.04, lvm, floppy

I've got a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.2 server that takes **over an hour** to boot.  I've looked into a few possible causes but haven't found anything definitive yet.

I'm using the new ubiquity installer with guided-lvm over the entire disk.  I manually created a swap partition and activated it after the install finished.  I tried the same setup on a VM with no issues, so I don't think it's the problem described in these links:

- https://www.hiroom2.com/2018/05/01/ubuntu-1804-lvm-swap-wait-for-root-en/
- https://tinycp.com/community/show/solved-print-req-error-i-o-error-dev-fd0-sector-0,43.html
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390618&page=2

systemd-analyze blame shows:

```
     18.661s apt-daily.service
     10.376s systemd-udev-settle.service
     10.260s dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2dsystem\x2d\x2dlv.device
      9.639s cloud-init-local.service
      9.214s snapd.service
      7.875s lxd-containers.service
```

systemd-analyze shows:

```
Startup finished in 1h 2min 5.017s (kernel) + 1min 7.007s (userspace) = 1h 3min 12.024s
```

After POST, the normal messages fly by and then every 23 seconds I get this message:

```
Mar  7 15:02:19 server kernel: [   81.401001] floppy: error 10 while reading block 0
Mar  7 15:02:19 server kernel: [  104.223783] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
Mar  7 15:02:19 server kernel: [  104.224975] floppy: error 10 while reading block 0
Mar  7 15:02:19 server kernel: [  127.323255] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
```

until 3725 seconds, when the system finally mounts the filesystem:

```
Mar  7 15:02:19 server kernel: [ 3723.824233] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
Mar  7 15:02:19 server kernel: [ 3723.825351] floppy: error 10 while reading block 0
Mar  7 15:02:19 server kernel: [ 3724.161930] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Mar  7 15:02:19 server kernel: [ 3725.524789] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
```

The machine is and AMD FX-4100 on an AM3+ GA-78LMT-S2, if that helps.  I didn't see any option to disable a floppy controller as I skimmed through the BIOS options.

Why haven't I blacklisted the floppy driver?  Well, I'm a bit reluctant to try it since the end-to-end time to run a test is obviously 1 hour.  I thought I'd ask here and see if I can pin down the root cause before trying the "blacklist everything" approach.

*edit* more details:

```
server:~$ cat /etc/fstab
#UUID=916718a9-ca19-4694-966a-ae37994cbbb7 none swap sw 0 0
UUID=cb47423b-dfe1-4ccf-8ffc-4e3f408b5b32 / ext4 defaults 0 0
UUID=d13d95e4-f50e-4baf-bb44-491624accb26 /boot ext4 defaults 0 0
UUID=f2508087-1526-4976-9d81-7e35a85461af /mnt ext4 defaults 0 0



server:~$ sudo blkid
[sudo] password for david: 
/dev/sda2: UUID="d13d95e4-f50e-4baf-bb44-491624accb26" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="1e459a88-de12-41c5-b82f-42a115adb555"
/dev/sda3: UUID="6Jl4Uh-Ztjh-SaiV-D1M7-6Chz-x1IT-GBqmsu" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="4c56484e-f74b-4b10-b29a-da6815fef057"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-system--lv: UUID="cb47423b-dfe1-4ccf-8ffc-4e3f408b5b32" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: PARTUUID="5c6ca6ec-f0a9-47b8-9627-91955a7f3fd3"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap--lv: UUID="916718a9-ca19-4694-966a-ae37994cbbb7" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-data--lv: UUID="f2508087-1526-4976-9d81-7e35a85461af" TYPE="ext4"



server:~$ sudo lshw -C storage
  *-storage                 
       description: SATA controller
       product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 11
       bus info: pci@0000:00:11.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: storage pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=ahci latency=32
       resources: irq:22 ioport:ff00(size=8) ioport:fe00(size=4) ioport:fd00(size=8) ioport:fc00(size=4) ioport:fb00(size=16) memory:fe02f000-fe02f3ff
  *-usb
       description: Mass storage device
       product: Mass Storage Device
       vendor: Generic
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@2:3
       logical name: scsi1
       version: 1.00
       serial: 058F63646476
       capabilities: usb-2.00 scsi emulated scsi-host
       configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=250mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-ide
       description: IDE interface
       product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 14.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.1
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: ide msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=pata_atiixp latency=32
       resources: irq:16 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:fa00(size=16)
  *-scsi
       physical id: 1
       logical name: scsi6
       capabilities: emulated


server:~$ sudo lshw -C disk
[sudo] password for david: 
  *-disk                    
       description: SCSI Disk
       product: USB DISK
       vendor: SMI
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sdf
       version: 1100
       serial: AA00000000016831
       size: 3841MiB (4027MB)
       capabilities: removable
       configuration: ansiversion=4 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
     *-medium
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/sdf
          size: 3841MiB (4027MB)
          capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
          configuration: signature=39f675eb
  *-disk:0
       description: SCSI Disk
       product: SD/MMC
       vendor: Generic-
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@7:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sdb
       version: 1.00
       capabilities: removable
       configuration: logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
     *-medium
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/sdb
  *-disk:1
       description: SCSI Disk
       product: Compact Flash
       vendor: Generic-
       physical id: 0.0.1
       bus info: scsi@7:0.0.1
       logical name: /dev/sdc
       version: 1.01
       capabilities: removable
       configuration: logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
     *-medium
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/sdc
  *-disk:2
       description: SCSI Disk
       product: SM/xD-Picture
       vendor: Generic-
       physical id: 0.0.2
       bus info: scsi@7:0.0.2
       logical name: /dev/sdd
       version: 1.02
       capabilities: removable
       configuration: logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
     *-medium
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/sdd
  *-disk:3
       description: SCSI Disk
       product: MS/MS-Pro
       vendor: Generic-
       physical id: 0.0.3
       bus info: scsi@7:0.0.3
       logical name: /dev/sde
       version: 1.03
       serial: 3
       capabilities: removable
       configuration: logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
     *-medium
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/sde
  *-disk
       description: ATA Disk
       product: ST3320820AS
       vendor: Seagate
       physical id: 0.1.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.1.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: E
       serial: 5QF5MB4F
       size: 298GiB (320GB)
       capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
       configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=e4bca90d-e6e1-4ac2-acd3-8f6686bed984 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
```

Comment: I'll ask an obvious question... do you even have a floppy disk controller/drive? If so, is there a disk inside? Check your BIOS for either a floppy disk controller enable/disable, or a boot order that includes a floppy disk in its path of devices. Disable it there, or change its order so it's not early. Check for a BIOS update.

Comment: No, I don't have a floppy disk port, controller, or drive in the machine.  There are no bios options for floppy disk controllers.  There is a "legacy usb" in the bios, but I don't think that option is related.  I updated the Bios to the latest version and have the same result.

Comment: Let me see your `/etc/fstab` and `sudo lshw -C disk`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema I guess no line breaks allowed in comments, using ------ to separate...
#UUID=1234 none swap sw 0 0  ------

UUID=1234 / ext4 defaults 0 0 ------

UUID=1234 /boot ext4 defaults 0 0 ------

UUID=1234 /mnt ext4 defaults 0 0

Comment: Please edit the output(s) as an edit to your question. It's impossible to read when put into the comments. Thanks!

Comment: Also show me `sudo blkid` and `sudo lshw -C storage`.

Comment: @heynnema Added output of both commands.

Comment: Thanks. You forgot `sudo lshw -C disk`, Do you have a USB flash key inserted? Or a CD-ROM/DVD?

Comment: @heynnema I have a usb drive and a card reader attached, so there are a few extra drives.  FYI, though, I decided to try and blacklist the floppy drive for fun and of course that fixed the boot problem.  Any idea why the kernel doesn't give up after a reasonable number of tries?

Comment: Good news! How/where did you blacklist fd0? And yes, it should timeout faster...

Comment: @heynnema I tried it in the kernel boot options `modprobe.blacklist=floppy`.  I'll have to make it permanent but at least I can boot faster than once an hour.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something about my setup causes the kernel to search for a floppy drive, so to rule this out I added a kernel boot parameter `modprobe.blacklist=floppy` and now the system boots in ~1 minute.

I made it permanent by running:

```
echo "blacklist floppy" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-floppy.conf

sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Thanks for the diagnosis help.